# Get to the handled event instance in HandleExternalEventActivity

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, state-machine

I have state machine, some state owns by HandleExternalEventActivity. It accepts some event with simple string flag. Basing on this string I need dispatch which next state must be activated. Most obvious is use IfElseActivity, but I have no idea how to get to this string from IfElse.
Most simplest way to place property on entire state-machine, but I would like avoid on some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of the HandleExternalEventActivity and add a dependency property to that. There is a command line utility WCA.exe which will create preconfigured activities base on your external data contracts and do exactly that.